# ArgMax returns the input

Tags: mathematical-optimization, maximum

I am new to Mathematica so I don't know if I am missing something.

I am trying to use `ArgMax` for a specific function I have, which includes `Cos[x]` inside. However, the function doesn't return any closed form or any results besides outputting the input. I put a simple function to understand where the problem is, which is shown below:

Input:

```
$Assumptions = b > 0 && 0<=x<=π && Element[b, Reals]&& Element[x, Reals]
ArgMax[{b Cos[x]}, {x}]
```

Output:

[image: output]

Here the function should give 0 as output, however it doesn't. Any idea why it is behaving this way? I am using notebooks from the Wolfram Cloud.

Comment: Two things. First, I don't see in the documentation that `ArgMax` depens on `$Assumptions`. According to the documentation, you add your constraints to the argument. Second, since the constraint on `b` leaves the max unbounded, I don't think it'll be able to solve it as you've set it up. This emits a message, but does produce a solution: `ArgMax[{b Cos[x], x >= 0 && x <= Pi && b > 0}, {x, b}]`.

Answer (score 0):

@leric is correct the problem is unbounded as defined.  The constraints can be either separately defined or placed in the ArgMax[] statement.  Remember the constraints, if specified separately, are global in the notebook.

```
During evaluation of In[164]:= ArgMax::natt: The maximum is not attained at any point satisfying the given constraints. 

Out[165]= {Indeterminate, Indeterminate}
```